# What does direction of EMF mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, induction

In faraday's law it mention's direction of EMF( like in closed loopit is clockwise or anticlockwise depending on direction of motion of magnet) but defination of EMF is roughly Potential diffrence between two points then what does flow of EMF make any sense in faraday's law?

Comment: *"but defination of EMF is roughly Potential diffrence between two points"* - that isn't correct is it? See, for example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force#Formal_definitions)

Answer (score 1):

When you change the magnetic flux through a surface bounded by a closed loop an emf is induced in the loop. That means that if a test charge is taken once around the loop in one direction, the work done per unit charge on the test charge by the electric field that curls round the changing magnetic field is, by definition, the emf. The direction of the emf is that of the electric field. If the loop is an actual loop made of an electrically conducting material, then charge will flow round by itself, in the direction of the emf. In this case the work that has to be done against resistive forces is supplied by the emf.

No potential differences are involved. In fact the whole notion of potential difference is inapplicable to this situation. Potential differences arise from static or quasi-static charges, and you don't have these here.

However if you had a conducting loop with a gap in it, and certain configurations of changing magnetic flux, the emf can make electrons pile up on one cut end of the loop, leaving the other end depleted of electrons and positive. We would then have quasi static charges and a potential difference between the ends. [Electrons will stop flowing, even if there is still changing magnetic flux, when the electric field in the ring due to this changing flux is balanced by the opposing electric field due to the charge separation.] Note that even in this case, where there *is* a pd, the direction of the emf may be defined independently of the notion of pd.

Comment: Suggested edit:  "When you change the magnetic flux through a [surface bounded by a ]closed loop an emf is induced in the loop"

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of it myself, but having read the comment by @AlfredCentauri, I agree with him.    A loop is a one-dimensional object.  The flux passes through the two-dimensional surface bounded by the loop, not the one-dimensional boundary.  Pedantic?  Maybe.   Accurate?  Yes.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri. But surely if flux passes once through a surface bonded by a loop, then it passes through the loop itself. If a dog jumps through a piece of paper stretched across a wooden hoop, then it has jumped through the hoop. Please tell me why I ought to mention the surface. I ask in humility.

Comment: @Garyp. Got it. So the dog doesn't jump through the hoop but through the hole in the hoop. Fair enough. Many thanks And to AC.

Comment: Philip, it's not uncommon to see "magnetic flux through a loop" in the literature so,  like @garyp suggests, I'm being quite pedantic here. But, it's *magnetic field lines* that 'pass through the hole in the loop'. Since the magnetic flux through a surface is a surface integral of the (normal component) of the magnetic field *on* the surface, I don't see a picture of magnetic flux passing through the loop. Now, I've also seen in the literature, and I have written in answers here, the phrase "magnetic flux *threading* a loop".  For example: [Magnetic flux quantum](https://tinyurl.com/y289d3qs)

Comment: Interesting. Why I  see a picture of flux passing through the loop is that, because $\vec \nabla.\vec B=0,$ we get the same value for flux whatever surface we integrate over, provided that the surface is bounded by the loop. The boundary is the key thing. To me the surface integral remaining the same from surface to surface is analogous to the (streamline) flow of an incompressible fluid and hints at magnetic field lines...

Answer (score 1):

> but defination of EMF is roughly Potential diffrence between two points

There is a "potential difference" only if there is a "potential". How does an electric potential arise? According to Maxwell's/Heaviside's equations (the equations we know today were first formulated by Heaviside based upon Maxwell's work)

$$\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

if, and only if $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = 0$ does $\nabla \times \vec{E}= 0$

If $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ then $E$ is a conservative field, and consequently there exists a scalar potential field $V$ such that

$$E = -\nabla V$$

Thus, when there is no time-varying magnetic field, then there is a well defined scalar potential, and hence "potential differences". [Actually, there are many possible scalar potential fields, each differing from each other by a constant. But when we take a potential difference, those constants don't matter]. When there *is* a time-varying magnetic field, then there is a path dependent "voltage drop", however, there is not a path independent "potential difference".

So, in the case of electromagnetic induction, we must cast aside the notion that EMF is equal to "potential difference". A suitable definition of EMF in the case of electromagnetic induction is

$$ \mathscr E_{induced} = {\int_a^b}_C \vec{E_{rot}} \cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

where

- $\vec{E_{rot}}$ is the divergence free (or rotational) component of the $\vec{E}$ field, and is a solution to the equation

$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E_{rot}} = \frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$

- the integral is taken from a point $a$ on the wire to a point $b$ on the wire along the wire path $C$

> then what does flow of EMF make any sense in faraday's law?

There are two cases. If we form a closed loop, the equation above becomes

$$ \mathscr E_{induced} = {\oint}_C \vec{E_{rot}} \cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

However, because a closed loop integral of a conservative vector field is 0, we can integrate over $\vec{E}$ rather than $\vec{E_{rot}}$ and get the same answer. [$\vec{E}$ is just the sum of $\vec{E_{rot}}$ and a conservative vector field.]

$$ \mathscr E_{induced} = {\oint}_C \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

Or one can use the non-loop equation

$$ \mathscr E_{induced} = {\int_a^b}_C \vec{E_{rot}} \cdot d\vec{\ell}$$

with Kirchhoff's voltage law to solve a loop where there may be different currents in different sections, but between nodes $a$ and $b$ along curve $C$, there is uniform current.

Comment: Hello! Nice to see you here :). While reading your answer, I had a small doubt in the last part, you mentioned two cases but wrote down three integral equations

Comment: @Buraian Hi. :-). The two cases are open curve integral, and closed loop integral. The second closed loop integral is just replacing the $E_{rot}$ with $E$ because the integral of the conservative part is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The "direction" or polarity of a source emf is taken to be the direction it causes an electric current to flow. Since electric current is defined in terms of the motion of positively charged particles, it is the direction that positive charges are pushed.